# Docker not pulling updated php version

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to update php version on the Docker

This is how my `Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -d /home/ubuntu ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/.composer && \
    chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER ubuntu
```

I have changed the php version to **7.3**, and I tried to delete all docker containers and recreate it `docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)`. And then I built my docker containers using `docker-compose build --nocache --pull`.

docker-compose.yaml file looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    image: myapp
    container_name: myapp-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - myapp
```

But still the php version is stated as 7.2.

Any advice?

Comment: Similar issue, I removed the volumes that are used

Comment: Can you add the compose file?

Comment: @Khanna111 I tried this  `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`, but still didn't work. @anemyte added compose file

Comment: I did this to clean and then build image: docker stop $(docker ps -a -q); docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) ; docker rmi $(docker images -q);  docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all containers/images/networks/.. run:

```
docker system prune -a
```

Then try to build the image.

If that don't works: can you give the logs, where the wrong version will pulled?